# How to disable all strongSwan logging?

Tags: strongswan

Tried the following but that didn’t work.

```
config setup
  charondebug="ike -1, knl -1, cfg -1"
```

My gut feeling is it has something to do with `/etc/strongswan.d/charon-logging.conf`?

I have read the [docs](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/LoggerConfiguration) but want to make sure I don’t miss something.

Currently, I have the following which appears to disable most (if not all) logging.

```
charon {
    filelog {
        charon {
            default = -1
        }
    }
    syslog {
        auth {
            default = -1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your end goal? This sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: @Ginnungagap I am a privacy and security researcher. Once a server is up and running, I don’t want to log things.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [StrongSwan documentation](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/LoggerConfiguration):

> By default, the IKE daemon charon logs via syslog(3) using the LOG_AUTHPRIV (only messages on log level 0) and LOG_DAEMON (all log levels) facilities. The default log level for all subsystems is 1.
>
> <...>
>
> Unlike charon, charon-systemd logs to the systemd journal and not syslog, by default.

Which means that unless you've configured additional loggers (like a `charon` file logger), all you need is:

```
charon {
    syslog {
        daemon {
            default = -1
       }
   }
}
```

If you're using systemd, add this to avoid logging to the journal:

```
charon-systemd : charon {
    journal {
        default = -1
   }
}
```

I'll repeat for anyone stumbling on this: do not do this unless you have very specific privacy concerns, it hinders security auditing, debugging and post-compromise analysis.

Comment: Can you please show a complete example how to avoid logging when using systemd. Like the complete charon-logging.conf file. For some reason charon jsut keeps logging :-(

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to disable logging in strongswan configuration and I am not using `charon-systemd`.

I have setup filtering in rsyslog (`/etc/rsyslog.d/strongswan.conf`):

```
:programname, isequal, "charon" stop
```

This is not perfect, but at least no logs in files...